# Convert String (2015-FEB-17) to Date (20150217) format

Tags: c#

I tried the following but couldn't get it

```
string s= "2015-FEB-17";

//I want it to be converted to date format as 
 date = "20150217"

//I tried doing as  follows but didn't work 
 var myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "yyyy-MMM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: this is a very simple task that you could have easily used Google to find a quick answer not to mention `SO`

Comment: I am always tempted to press the downvote button when someone speaks of _date format_. Dates don't have a format. (unless you are talking about the internal disposition of bits that represent the date value). Dates could be represented for us humans as a string formatted in numerous ways

Comment: I am always tempted to press the downvote button when a poster hasn't done even the smallest amount of due diligence to find the answer to their question before posting it here.  I cannot resist temptation.

Comment: Sorry all I missed to add .ToString("yyyyMMdd") at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not shorten it since you are using the `.ToString("yyyyMMdd")` you are dropping the time portion of the new value

```
string sDateStr = "2015-FEB-17";
var newDateFrmt = Convert.ToDateTime(sDateStr).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

`20150217` becomes the expected answer based on the format..

not to be redundant this approach can also be taken

```
string sDateStr = "2015-FEB-17";
var someDate = DateTime.ParseExact(sDateStr, "yyyy-MMM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var newDateFrmt = someDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime` uses `DateTime.Parse`, which means this will only work if "yyyyMMdd" is a recognized date format in the current culture.

Comment: My culture on my machine is set to dateformat of mm/dd/yy so I think that your argument is invalid understand what the .ToString() overload does @woz

Comment: `.ToString()` does not change the functionality of `Convert.ToDateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MMM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var q = myDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

or just

```
var q = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MMM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                .ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: Better to pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` than `null`.

Answer (score 1):

`ParseExact` turns the string into a `DateTime`. You then need to format the `DateTime` as a string.

```
string s= "2015-FEB-17";
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MMM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string result = myDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd"); // now it's "20150217"
```

Also, you were missing dashes in the `ParseExact` format string.

If your application only handles US-style dates with no internationalization, it's best to specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.